# Expand An Alias That Executes Another Alias (Nested Alias)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have two aliases:

```
alias ls="ls -G"
alias la="ls -aFhlT"
```

I know that after you type your alias, but before you execute, you can type <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> (probably <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>, but possibly <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd>) to expand what you've typed.

So, if I expand my alias `la` using this method I get:

```
ls -aFhlT
```

However, what I really want is to see:

```
ls -G -aFhlT
```

Is there any way to achieve this besides typing <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> a second time?

--OR--

Is there any way to confirm that my execution of `la` actually executed `ls -G -aFhlT` (other than knowing how nested aliases work and trusting that it did what I think it did)?

I'm trying to do this on macOS, but a general bash solution will also be accepted.

Comment: Aliases are an interactive-only feature (in the optional "user portability" section of the POSIX sh standard) -- they're not available during script execution without setting a non-default flag, and programming (writing scripts, in the shell tag) is our focus here. Thus, as a note for the future, questions about their management is probably a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: ...btw, if you used functions for this -- as in `ls() { command ls -G "$@"; }; la() { ls -aFhlt "$@"; }` -- tracing with `set -x` would show the nested execution.

Comment: `set -x` may well be the place to look for an answer to the second branch of your question, regardless.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy. I will keep the "scripting" focus of stackoverflow in mind for next time.
`set -x; la; set +x` does indeed print out the first line as `+ ls -G -aFhlT`...along with a whole lot of extra info at the end! Using your function recommendation, `set -x; la; set +x` prints 4 lines to ultimately show the same result:
`+ la
+ ls -aFhlT
+ command ls -G -aFhlT
+ ls -G -aFhlT`
I could see a function like `xtrace() { set -x; eval "$@" > /dev/null; set +x; }` being useful. Not sure if `eval` here is better than just using `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Comment: I'd suggest `xtrace() { local retval; set -x; "$@"; retval=$?; set +x; return "$retval"; }` -- much less [perilous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) than `eval`, especially with the unquoted expansion munging the argument list before it's assembled into a single string to evaluate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy With your above xtrace function, `xtrace la` prints out "-bash: la: command not found". This is with `la` defined as an alias. It works fine if `la` is a function. What is the best way to get the same functionality if you pass an alias instead of a function/command/builtin (eval will work but I don't want to use it if it's frowned upon)?

Comment: I'm from the irc.freenode.org #bash school of thought, where the [automatic answer to any question about aliases](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/alias) has historically been "if you have to ask, use a function instead". That said, we could cook up something that uses `eval` safely; lessee...

Comment: `xtrace() { local eval_cmd retval; printf -v eval_cmd '%q ' "$@"; set -x; eval "$eval_cmd"; retval=$?; set +x; return "$retval"; }` should support aliases if `eval` does in general, and doesn't introduce the usual set of `eval`-related bugs.

Comment: Instead, just change the first alias to say: `alias ls=“\ls -G”`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question rides the fine line between using an alias and using a function. When aliases get even slightly complicated, it is generally better to write a function instead. That being said, I *did* find a solution for this question that allows for expanding aliases as desired.

I wrote a bash function for this:

```
xtrace() {
    local eval_cmd
    printf -v eval_cmd '%q ' "${@}"
    { set -x
      eval "${eval_cmd}"
    } 2>&1 | grep '^++'
    return "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
}
```

The `-v` flag of `printf` will store the output of `printf` in the specified variable.

The `printf` format string `%q` will print the associated argument (`$@` in this case) **shell-quoted**, reusable as input. This eliminates the dangers associated with passing arbitrary code/commands to `eval`.

I then use a command group `{ ... }` so I can control the functionality of `set -x`, which tells bash to print a trace of all executed commands. For my purposes, I do not care about any output except for the fully expanded command, so I redirect `stderr` and `grep` for the output line that starts with "++". This will be the line that shows the fully expanded command.

Finally, I return the value of `PIPESTATUS[0]`, which contains the return code of the *last* command executed in the command group (i.e. the `eval` command).

Thus, we will get something like the following:

```
$ xtrace la; echo $?
++ ls -G -aFhlT
0
```

Much thanks to @CharlesDuffy for the `set -x` recommendation as well as the input sanitation for `eval`.

Comment: this ruins commands with arguments -- notice the space after `%q` in Charles' posting